# configuring Ideavim (phpstorm plugin)

Tags: php, vim, phpstorm, ideavim

I want to reconfigure certain keys in the ideavim plugin for phpstorm. Specifcally change `0` to act like `^` in normal mode.
Is this possible? I tried looking at the keymaps settings for vim, but it doesn't have an action called go to beginning of line(ignoring whitespace) and strangely all the keys for vim are shown as regular keys (home , end etc) and not vim keys.

Anybody knows whats up?

Comment: Regarding [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19396894/367456) you a bit quickly deleted: https://eval.in/private/cc8fc1f5c4da80 - unable to reproduce for both cases, it does not give the error you ask about.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out !

settings > keymaps > select the chosen keymap (vim) > in the list drill down to plugins > ideavim > and edit away!

Answer (score 0):

The IdeaVim plugin also supports a subset of the vimrc commands.

You have to store your file in `~/.ideavimrc`

You could for example enter there:

```
nnoremap 0 ^
```